# Rails: Pass Tempfile to Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I work on a mailing endpoint that gathers attachments as a Tempfile, then I need to pass them to a Sidekiq Worker to upload them to AWS.

My problem is that I'm stuck at the point I'm trying to persist the Tempfile and then open it in my worker. I don't know with what I should open my Tempfile (path, filename...).

Here is my function that will call the worker:

```
if @email
    # Remove Tempfile autodelete
    @email.attachments.each {|t| ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(t.tempfile)}

    # Griddler Email to hash for Sidekiq
    email = {
        attachments: @email.attachments.map {|att| {
            type: att.content_type,
            name: att.original_filename
        }},
        raw_text: @email.raw_text,
        raw_html: @email.raw_html,
        from: @email.from,
        subject: @email.subject,
        to: @email.to,
        cc: @email.cc
    }

    EmailResponseWorker.perform_async email
end
```

Here I use `ObjectSpace.undefine_finalizer(t.tempfile)` to disable auto delete.

Then in my Sidekiq Worker:

```
def perform(email)
  @email = email

  attachments = @email['attachments'].inject([]) do |arr, file|
    object = S3_BUCKET.objects["attachments/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/#{file['name']}"].write(Tempfile.open(file['name']), acl: :public_read)
    arr << {url: object.public_url.to_s, type: file['type'], name: file['name']}
  end
end
```

Here attachments['name'] is the name of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get `path` from the tempfile and handle it as a usual file path:

```
path: att.tempfile.path
```

it is path to the tempfile itself, `original_filename` is the filename passed by client, not the one you need.

Do not forget to unlink it after the job has completed successfully.

Comment: Then after in my Worker I juste have to use `Tempfile.open(path)` ?

Comment: @IsmaelBourg yes. But better just as a regular `File.open`, so you can close and unlink it more explicitly and not wait for GC to fire

Comment: Works perfectly ! Thanks !